# Is there a way to avoid repetition in linq projections that depend on expressions?

Tags: c#, linq

So example program:

```
    class Cat
    {
        public bool IsMale { get; set;}
        public int TailLength { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal ClawAttackFrequency { get; set; }
        public List<DateTime> FeedingTimes { get; set; }
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cats = new List<Cat>();
        var someData = cats
            .Select(x => new
            {
                x.Name,
                x.IsMale,
                LatestFeedingTime = x.FeedingTimes.Max(y => (DateTime?)y)
            })
            .Select(x => new
            {
                x.Name,
                x.IsMale,
                x.LatestFeedingTime,
                WasFedRecently = x.LatestFeedingTime.HasValue && x.LatestFeedingTime.Value >= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1)
            });
    }
```

This is just a toy program that does nothing but it illustrates my problem which is that in order to avoid having to duplicate the expression for LatestFeedingTime I have to instead make two projections and duplicate a bunch of properties.

The alternative would have been:

```
    var someData = cats
        .Select(x => new
        {
            x.Name,
            x.IsMale,
            LatestFeedingTime = x.FeedingTimes.Max(y => (DateTime?)y),
            WasFedRecently = (x.FeedingTimes.Max(y => (DateTime?)y)).HasValue && (x.FeedingTimes.Max(y => (DateTime?)y)).Value >= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1)
        });
```

But this duplicates a tricky expression instead.

Is there any way to get the best of both worlds in c#. Like a way to declare an expression and then use in twice in the same projection?

Comment: I see now after a few answers that I oversimplifed my example. The real problem is more related to linq to entites. I will accept one of the answers in case someone actually wonders this and maybe post a better question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at doing it this way:

```
var someData =
    from x in cats
    let LatestFeedingTime = x.FeedingTimes.Max(y => (DateTime?)y)
    select new
    {
        x.Name,
        x.IsMale,
        LatestFeedingTime,
        WasFedRecently =
            LatestFeedingTime.HasValue
            && LatestFeedingTime.Value >= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1)
    };
```

It certainly eliminates the duplication in your code, but under the hood it is still generating the same code.

You can even shorten it to this:

```
var someData =
    from x in cats
    let LatestFeedingTime = x.FeedingTimes.Max(y => (DateTime?)y)
    select new
    {
        x.Name,
        x.IsMale,
        LatestFeedingTime,
        WasFedRecently = LatestFeedingTime >= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define a Build method returning what you wish

```
    var someData = cats
        .Select (Cat.BuildData);
```

And inside your

```
   public static Something BuildData (Cat cat) {
```

you can use any local variable...

Answer (score 0):

Just use a statement lambda where you can use a local variable

```
var someCats = cats.Select(x =>
{
    var lft = x.FeedingTimes.Max(y => (DateTime?)y);
    return new
    { 
        x.Name, 
        x.IsMale, 
        LatestFeedingTime = lft, 
        WasFedRecently = lft >= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1)
    };
});
```

But I feel sorry for your cat if you consider it being fed recently as potentially being fed in the last 48 hrs!